# Problem with ion-input in the iOS platform ionic-3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have problems with input on iOS. On Android, everything works fine. After entering the application, I click on the input and the keyboard appears. Then when I remove the keyboard and click on the input again, another part of the screen is pressed. Did someone face such a problem?

I tried `scrollAssist: false`, `autoFocusAssist: false`, but does not help.

[image: live demo]

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
        name: '__ForeverDB',
        driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(ForeverApp, {
  scrollAssist: false,
  autoFocusAssist: false,
  tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
        platforms: {
            ios: {
                backButtonText: 'Назад',
            }
        }
    }),
],
```

Comment: I also had this issue, first I tried my app on iOS simulator and had this bug everytime, but not always on physical device. I don't really know why, but downgrading to ionic 3.8.x solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening with the keyboard plugin on iOS 12.

When the keyboard hides the HTML document does not return to its original height, all the content is visible but not avaliable to be "touched"

Try this:

On the `app.component.ts`, inside the constructor, every time the keyboard shows set the height as auto for the HTML tag using `renderer2`.

When the keyboard hides set the height as 101vh and this will make the app to readjust the height.

```
import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

//Get the HTML tag
let html = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0);

this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
    this.renderer2.setStyle(html, 'height','101vh')
});

this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() => {
    this.renderer2.setStyle(html, 'height','auto')
});
```